# Construct a triangle with $m_b = a$ and one of angles

Tags: geometry

I have a question for construct a triangle with know $m_b = a$ and one of angles. In this question, There may be a possibility of drawing mode or under certain circumstances be able to draw it. (E.g angle). This question wants us to find those conditions.

1) If we know $m_b = a$ and $\angle C$
I solved this question. It's my pictures.
[image: image1]
We can see only condition for this question is $\angle C$. If It's more than 90, Then we can't draw it.

2) If we know $m_b = a$ and $\angle B$
Thanks Mos Black for answer these question. It's just shape of that.
[image]

3) If we know $m_b = a$ and $\angle A$

for two above questions, I work but I couldn't find anything. because of question, I don't know I can't do it or it is not possible to do!
Is it possible to help me?
I'm sorry for bad English too.

Comment: Do we know the numerical value of $a$? Other a unique triangle is not possible. We get inifinite number of similar triangles.

Comment: It's just a number. Question give us a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1) For the constrution of the triangle ABC given $m_b=a$ and $\angle C$ the necessary and sufficient condition of the constrution to be possible is that $\angle C <90$.

2) is always possible. This can be verified from the following:

$m_b=a$ gives using appollinius theorem $c^2-\frac{b^2}{2}=a^2$........(1)

And from cosince rule we have $\frac{c^2+a^2-b^2}{2ac}=t=\cos B$......(2)

Now eliminating $b^2$ from (1) and (2) we get

$c^2-2act-3a^2=0$ which always has  a positive root in $c$.

So, its always possible.

for 2) a geometric construction is as follows:

Construct a line segment of length $a$ and constuct $\angle CBK$.

Now, from $C$ draw a line $l_1$ parallel to $BK$.

Extend $BC$ to $D$ such that $CD=BC$.

With $B$ as the center draw a circle of radius $BD$ and let it cut $l_1$ at $E$.

Draw line parallel to $BC$ passing through $E$ and let it cut $BK$ at $A$.

You have your triangle $ABC$

Comment: thanks for answer. construction is difficult for me in geometry.

Comment: can you help me for third question too?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your problem, but I'll offer some information which will hopefully help you.

Two triangles can be proven congruent if you can show that one of the four following conditions is met:

1. All three sides are the same.
2. Two sides and their included angle are the same.
3. Two angles and their included side are the same.
4. Two angles and their non-included side are the same.

The reason I say this is because if you know the information that satisfies one of the above 4 situations, then you have a defined triangle (since each of the possibilities are congruent to each other). You are given only a side and an angle (correct me if I'm wrong), so none of the 4 conditions can be met, so there are multiple possible triangles (either 2 or infinity).

Comment: Thanks but atleast we have two triangle. Can you help me construct one of them for second question